# Mypaint causes cursor to change

Tags: 14.04, cursor

I have recently fell in love with the painting software Mypaint, but I have run into a rather annoying problem. whenever I begin to use a larger brush, and the circle cursor becomes as big as a dime or bigger, the cursor becomes a large circle with two small pointers at the top on either side. the only way i've found to fix it is to log out then back in again or to use a text software to make the cursor disappear then reappear. does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here (large circle with two small pointers) but only when i select a large eraser. I think it's related to the cursor size, because at a high zoom level, with a normal brush, the cursor also breaks : it changes to stranges crossed lines.

The only solution i found is to set *Freehand cursor type* to *Réticule* (sorry i don't know the word in english) in Preferences>View, but you can't see the brush size limits anymore...